# Given an undirected graph G = (V, E), determine whether G is a complete graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, np

I'm pretty sure this problem is P and not NP, but I'm having difficulty coming up with a polynomially bound algorithm to solve it.

Comment: All problems in P are also in NP. You mean "is P and not NP-complete" (or "not NP-hard").

Comment: Exactly where are you stuck? Do you have an algorithm that's not P? Or one that you can't prove is P? Or stuck on the definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can :

1. check that number of edges in the graph is `n(n-1)/2`.
2. check that each vertice is connected to exaclty `n-1` distinct vertices.

This will run in `O(V²)`, which is polynomial.

Hope it helped.

Comment: You gotta be more pedantic with your symbols. It will not run in O(V^2) because you haven't even described how `V` relates to `n`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an O(|E|) algorithm that also has a small constant.

It's trivial to enumerate every edge in a complete graph. So all you need to do is scan your edge list and verify that every such edge exists.

For each edge (i, j), let f(i, j) = i*|V| + j. Assuming vertices are numbered 0 to |V|-1.

Let `bitvec` be a bit vector of length |V|<sup>2</sup>, initialized to 0.

For each edge (i, j), set `bitvec[f(i, j)]` = 1.

G is a complete graph if and only if every element of `bitvec` == 1.

This algorithm not only touches E once, but it's also completely vectorizable if you have a scatter instruction. That also means it's trivial to parallelize.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an O(E) algorithm:

1. Use O(E) as it is input time, to scan the graph
2. Meanwhile, record each vertex p's degree, increase degree **only if** the neighbor is not p itself (self-connecting edge) **and** is not a vertex q where p and q has another edge counted already (multiple edge), these checking can be done in O(1)
3. Check if all vertex's degree is |V|-1, this step is O(V), if Yes then it is a complete graph

Total is O(E)

Answer (score 0):

For a given graph G = (V,E), check for each pair u, v in the V, and see if edge (u,v) is in E.
The total number of u, v pairs are |V|*(|V|-1)/2. As a result, with a time complexity of  O(|V|^2), you can check and see if a graph is complete or not.