# Algorithm to check if a digraph is complete

Tags: java, algorithm, graph-algorithm

Is there a known algorithm for checking whether a graph is a [complete digraph](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CompleteDigraph.html)?

Ideally, I'd like to find a ready-to-use method from [JGraphT Java library](https://jgrapht.org/guide/UserOverview).

Alternatively, I've found the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105886/given-an-undirected-graph-g-v-e-determine-whether-g-is-a-complete-graph/52246899) regarding completeness check of an undirected graph. Would the following modification work for checking completeness of a directed graph?

1. check that number of directed edges in the graph is `n(n-1)`
2. check that each vertice is directly connected to exactly `n-1` distinct vertices

If I don't miss anything and these conditions are sufficient I could implement these checks by myself, but I'd prefer to use existing implementation from the library if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this JGraphT method?

[`GraphTests#isComplete`](https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/GraphTests.html#isComplete-org.jgrapht.Graph-)

it says that it checks for digraphs as well.

> Test whether a graph is complete. A complete undirected graph is a
>   simple graph in which every pair of distinct vertices is connected by
>   a unique edge. **A complete directed graph is a directed graph in which
>   every pair of distinct vertices is connected by a pair of unique edges
>   (one in each direction)**.

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for! BTW I checked that this method actually checks if the number of edges is equal to n(n-1) assuming the graph is simple.

Answer (score 1):

If your graph doesn't have more than one edge going from and to the same nodes that is the easiest way to do it.

You cannot have a graph that is not complete and has that many `(n*(n-1))` edge *without duplicated edges.*